# "Let me know it" or "Let me know"

Tags: word-usage

Do you need to add "it" after "Let me know" so it becomes "Let me know it"? Or is this not really necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [ell.se].

Comment: It depends on the context. You should provide your situation to make it clear.

Comment: The issue that the poster is asking about here seems pretty straightforward to me. Luckily, Nonnal provided a helpful answer before the question got closed.

Answer (score 4):

In the vast majority of common examples, when used in isolation, **"let me know"** is probably the phrase that you want.

You would only include the word "it" if you are making specific reference to an antecedent recently mentioned, *and* if that antecedent is a singular third person noun that could reasonably be replaced with the word *it*.

For example:

> I'll be available later if you want to see a movie. Let me know *[i.e. if you do]*.
>
> When you go grocery shopping, let me know *[i.e. that you are going]*.
>
> If you know the answer, let me know it *[i.e. the answer]*, too.
>
> If you know the answers, let me know them *[i.e. the answers]*, too.

It's worth noting that, even in the last two examples, you could just say "let me know" and the sentences would still be grammatically correct.

> If you know the answer, let me know, too.
>
> If you know the answers, let me know, too.

Comment: Yes, as you are requesting for something previously mentioned to be "informed", you don't need to put an object after "know".

Answer (score 0):

The use of "it" in that phrase is abnormal (at least in the Western hemisphere it is).

"Let me know" isn't too abnormal, but the phrase "What is it?" (while being somewhat intrusive, although that mostly relies on your tone) would probably suit you better.